# Why is forcing major compaction on a table not ideal?

Tags: cassandra

Consider a scenario where a table partitions with thousands of deleted rows. When reading from the table, Cassandra has to scan over thousands of deleted rows before it gets to the live rows.

A common workaround is to manually run a compaction on a node to forcibly get rid of tombstones.

What are the downsides of forcing major compaction on a table (with `nodetool compact`) and what is the best practice recommendation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Background

When [forcing a major compaction](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra-oss/3.x/cassandra/tools/toolsCompact.html) on a table [configured with the `SizeTieredCompactionStrategy` (STCS)](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql-oss/3.3/cql/cql_reference/cqlCreateTable.html#compactSubprop__compactionSubpropertiesSTCS), all the SSTables on the node get compacted together into a single large SSTable. Due to its size, the resulting SSTable will likely never get compacted out since similar-sized SSTables are not available as compaction candidates. This creates additional issues for the nodes since tombstones do not get evicted and keep accumulating, affecting the cluster's performance.

### Caveats

We understand that cluster administrators use major compaction as a way of evicting tombstones which have accumulated as a result of high-delete workloads which in most cases is due to an incorrect data model.

The recommendation in this post does NOT constitute a solution to the underlying issue users face. It should not be considered a long-term fix to the data model problem.

### Recommendation

In Apache Cassandra 2.2, [CASSANDRA-7272](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-7272) introduced a huge improvement which splits the output of `nodetool compact` into multiple files which are 50% then 25% then 12.5% of the original table size until the smallest chunk is 50MB for tables using STCS.

When using major compaction as a last resort for evicting tombstones, use the `--split-output` (or shorthand `-s`) to take advantage of this new feature:

```
$ nodetool compact --split-output -- <keyspace> <table>
```

**NOTE** - This feature is only available from Cassandra 2.2 and newer versions.

Also see [How to split large SSTables on another server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73019068/). Cheers!