# What is the best way to get rid of big STCS sstables?

Tags: cassandra

What is the best possible way to get rid of the big sstables (hundreds of GB in size) created by STCS compaction?

Will it be `sstablesplit` or `nodetool compact -s`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those two commands perform different operations and the "best way" depends on what you want to achieve.

`sstablesplit` as its name suggests will split SSTables into smaller files so they can be selected as compaction candidates by `SizeTieredCompactionStrategy`. Note however that it is *an offline tool* so Cassandra needs to be shutdown in order to run the tool.

As a workaround, you can split large SSTables on another server. I've previously documented the detailed steps in [How do I split large SSTables on another server?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/314534/).

The "split" option (`-s` or `--split-output`) for `nodetool compact` will force what's called *a major compaction* that will split SSTables into files which are 50% then 25% then 12.5% of the original table size until the smallest file is 50MB. Note however that this option is only available from Cassandra 2.2 or later releases.

There are disadvantages for running a manual compaction which I've explained in [Why is forcing major compaction on a table not ideal?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/314531/) so it is something to be aware of.

Going back to your original question, what is "best" depends on your situation and will come down to whether you can afford to bring a node down or not. Hopefully the points I've raised above will help you decide. Cheers!

Comment: Nice explanation, bud!

Comment: I totally Agree Erick. Thanks a lot for your valuable advise

Answer (score 1):

SSTABLESPLIT is definitely the way to go.

Manually running compaction has a tendency to cause more problems that it's worth.