# Disk space is not released after compaction

Tags: cassandra

We have deleted some of the partionons of some tables in cassandra database. But after the delete space was not recliamed becuase of size-tiered compaction . Manualy compacted tables with `-s` options. we have cluster of having 2 data ceneters and each with 6 nodes, we ran compaction both the DC's of all nodes. But Disk usage on DC1 reduced but 6% increase on the other DC2. So please let me know the reason for this and also suggest me on the next steps 2 bring down the usage of disk on Dc2. for your information even load on both DC's are come down.

Even cleared old snapshots of around 1.3TB on all nodes

o/p command as of below comment 4 (`find /path/to/dir/ -printf '%s %p\n'| sort -nr | head -10`):

```
12434906818 /data1/cassandra/data/witsml/log_curve-c9311570d40d11e7af9a6b6facb54bee/.maxdatetimeindex_idx/md-283562-big-Data.db
4111835201 /data1/Full_Backup/data1/cassandra/data/system_distributed/parent_repair_history-deabd734b99d3b9c92e5fd92eb5abf14/snapshots/2022-08-05/md-680-big-Data.db
4111835201 /data1/Full_Backup/data1/cassandra/data/system_distributed/parent_repair_history-deabd734b99d3b9c92e5fd92eb5abf14/snapshots/2022-07-29/md-680-big-Data.db
4111835201 /data1/Full_Backup/data1/cassandra/data/system_distributed/parent_repair_history-deabd734b99d3b9c92e5fd92eb5abf14/snapshots/2022-07-22/md-680-big-Data.db
4111835201 /data1/Full_Backup/data1/cassandra/data/system_distributed/parent_repair_history-deabd734b99d3b9c92e5fd92eb5abf14/snapshots/2022-07-15/md-680-big-Data.db
4111835201 /data1/Full_Backup/data1/cassandra/data/system_distributed/parent_repair_history-deabd734b99d3b9c92e5fd92eb5abf14/snapshots/2022-07-08/md-680-big-Data.db
4111835201 /data1/Full_Backup/data1/cassandra/data/system_distributed/parent_repair_history-deabd734b99d3b9c92e5fd92eb5abf14/snapshots/2022-07-01/md-680-big-Data.db
4111835201 /data1/Full_Backup/data1/cassandra/data/system_distributed/parent_repair_history-deabd734b99d3b9c92e5fd92eb5abf14/snapshots/2022-06-24/md-680-big-Data.db
4111835201 /data1/cassandra/data/system_distributed/parent_repair_history-deabd734b99d3b9c92e5fd92eb5abf14/md-680-big-Data.db
3782418777 /data1/Full_Backup/data1/cassandra/data/system_distributed/parent_repair_history-deabd734b99d3b9c92e5fd92eb5abf14/snapshots/2022-08-05/md-1963-big-Data.db
```

Comment: Have you looked at a [similar post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/314532)? These things might help triage this better: 1. Version of the Cassandra (for e.g. OSS C* `3.11.10`) 2. Schema of the table 3. Exact query used to delete data 4. Also, could you post the output of command?
```
find /path/to/dir/ -printf '%s %p\n'| sort -nr | head -10
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer  :1 . version is Apache cassandra 3.11.2                                                (2) schema : total six tables                                                                                                              3 :  Delete from table where partition='x' and object_id=x

Comment: output :12434906818 /data1/cassandra/data/witsml/log_curve-c9311570d40d11e7af9a6b6facb54bee/.maxdatetimeindex_idx/md-283562-big-Data.db
4111835201 /data1/Full_Backup/data1/cassandra/data/system_distributed/parent_repair_history-deabd734b99d3b9c92e5fd92eb5abf14/snapshots/2022-08-05/md-680-big-Data.db
4111835201

Comment: 4111835201 /data1/Full_Backup/data1/cassandra/data/system_distributed/parent_repair_history-deabd734b99d3b9c92e5fd92eb5abf14/snapshots/2022-07-29/md-680-big-Data.db
4111835201 /data1/Full_Backup/data1/cassandra/data/system_distributed/parent_repair_history-deabd734b99d3b9c92e5fd92eb5abf14/snapshots/2022-07-22/md-680-big-Data.db
4111835201 /data1/Full_Backup/data1/cassandra/data/system_distributed/parent_repair_history-deabd734b99d3b9c92e5fd92eb5abf14/snapshots/2022-07-15/md-680-big-Data.db

Comment: complete output of command in your 4th question is added to end of the question

Answer (score 0):

So for possible reasons why space isn't reclaimed after running a major compaction, I can think of the following:

- A snapshot of a table is hard-linked to the SSTable file(s).
- The tombstones' `gc_grace_seconds` for the table has not expired (tombstones are still valid and won't get collected).

I would double-check the `gc_grace_seconds` (default of 10 days...864000 seconds) and maybe try running it again.

**NOTE: Future Googlers, avoid running `nodetool compact` at all costs.**

Compaction will likely *never* happen organically ever again, which means you'll need an ongoing ops process to run it regularly.