# What is the difference between nodetool commands "garbagecollect" vs "compact"?

Tags: cassandra

What is the difference between working procedure of below 2 commands. How differently these are working

nodetool garbagecollect

and

nodetool compact -s

Answer (score 0):

So `nodetool garbagecollect` runs a single-SSTable compaction, with the intent of removing the current, eligible tombstones.

`nodetool compact -s` as-is invokes compaction and splits the resulting SSTable files into smaller-sized files (instead of just one large file).  It is recommended to run this command while specifying both a target keyspace and table.

For more info on this one, check out [Why is forcing major compaction on a table not ideal?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/314531/why-is-forcing-major-compaction-on-a-table-not-ideal)

Comment: Thanks Aaron for clarifying.Actually in my project I saw this big sstable of 250 GB generated due to major compaction practice (with nodetool compact command) by previous team members. I tried to run nodetool compact -s with the intention to segrgate,but that never worked. seems its not working properly (V3.11.5). I am now planning for sstablesplit