# How do I free up disk space once I've deleted keyspaces?

Tags: cassandra

I have a 5 node production Apache Cassandra cluster with 1TB SSD on each node.We have data/key spaces stored since 2018 & as per our business requirement we need to preserve it till seven years for which we transfer it to cloud storage but is there any strategy available to archive key spaces on the cluster because all of my SSD's on every node are 90% full now & management is not providing cost approval to increase SSD size for which I have decided to delete/drop/purge old key spaces.Can you please guide steps to free up space on SSD once key spaces are deleted.

@ericramirez :Please comment your thoughts on this.

Details of cassandra cluster.

No.of nodes:-5
Apache Cassandra version:3.11.3 & 3.11.11 for some of the other cluster's
data dirctory size:- 1000GB per node

Answer (score 1):

You haven't provided what version of Cassandra you're running nor the output of running `nodetool status` command so, I'm going to take an educated guess while answering your question. Feel free to update your original questions with the answers to them for others to properly triage this.

Your question is exactly as it is asked [here](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/4.1/cassandra/faq/index.html#asynch-deletes).

> Q: I delete data from Cassandra, but disk usage stays the same. What gives?

> A: Data you write to Cassandra gets persisted to SSTables. Since SSTables are immutable, the data can’t actually be removed when you perform a delete, instead, a marker (also called a "tombstone") is written to indicate the value’s new status. Never fear though, on the first compaction that occurs between the data and the tombstone, the data will be expunged completely and the corresponding disk space recovered. See compaction for more detail.

By default, you need 50% free disk space with STCS and it appears that you're breaching past recommendation by running at 90% full in the disk space. This will prevent other operations activities like `compaction` which is required to clear up the old data that was deleted to reclaim free disk space.

Also, we shouldn't be running a manual compaction. See [a previous StackExchange answer here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/314532/258312) to know more about why it's not a good idea to do so.

[Recommended hardware specs](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cassandra/operating/hardware.html) is required is one of the minimal requirement to run this cluster efficiently. I didn't copy the entire text from that page and hence the hyperlinking.

Answer (score 0):

When you issue a `DROP KEYSPACE` or `DROP TABLE` command, Cassandra will automatically take a snapshot (backup) of the deleted keyspace or table on all the nodes by default to prevent data loss.

This is [configured in `cassandra.yaml`](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/cassandra-3.11/conf/cassandra.yaml#LL793C1-L794C1) with:

```
auto_snapshot: true
```

The data in the keyspace (or table) will no longer be accessible in Cassandra, but the underlying SSTables in the snapshot folder will still be on disk.

Once you have verified that you no longer need the snapshot (for example, it has been archived to cloud storage or off-server tape backup) then you can delete the snapshot using the following command:

```
$ nodetool clearsnapshot -t <snapshot_name>
```

This will release the inodes and free up space on the data disk. Note that you will need to run this command on all nodes in all DCs. Cheers!